# Fb ui share URL parameters in smartphones fb app

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a problem with the Fb ui share in some smartphones

this is the function:

```
function shareFB(data){
    FB.ui({
      method: 'share',
      href: data,
    }, function(response){});
}
```

and i use this code like this

```
$urlcode=get_permalink().'?id='.$result_array[proid].'&amp;varand='.$result_array[varand].'&amp;outimg='.$result_array[outimg].'&amp;xname='.$profile[first_name];

<a onclick="shareFB('<?php echo $urlcode ?>');" href="javascript:void(0);"> <div id="compartir" class="fb-btn"> <span class="fa fa-facebook"></span> | Compartir</div></a>
```

The output is something like this

```
shareFB('http://mydomain/slug/the-post/?id=1306715554533822&varand=765db80f406058a88591859458334060&outimg=6c2922e9a061cbd7ad03e5cbfe7157d6&xname=Miguel');
```

The problem is when in some smartphones i press the share button and then it takes me to the FB app. It only share until "id" url parameter, like this:

```
http://mydomain/slug/the-post/?id=1306715554533822
```

The other urls parameters dissapear

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I solved it shorting the url with goog.gl api

Greetings